# Check the url path is valid in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-hooks, jsx

this is the dynamic url

`../Assets/${product.code}/${image1}.png`

Some product have images and some does not have one. Therefore if the URL is not valid, I want to return different JSX element. Is there any way to check the validity of the image URL path ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do by `try/catch` if an error then returns a different JSX element.

```
setProductImageSrc() {
    try{
        const src = require(`../Assets/${product.code}/${image1}.png`)
        this.setState({ src });
    }
    catch(err){
        //Do whatever you want when the image failed to load here show return different JSX element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
There is an attribute on the image tag called onError, which can triggered a function when the image fails to load. So what you can do is when image fails to load either put different image i.e default image or different JSX element as your wish.

Example:

```
import {useState} from "react"

function App() {

const[iserror,Setiserror]=useState(false)

const errorFunc =()=>{
  Setiserror(true)
}

return (
   <div>
     {!iserror?<img onError={errorFunc} src="noimageurl" alt=""/>
     :<div>This will show when image fails to load</div>
   </div>
);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use fetch

```
const url="your-url-here"

fetch(url)
   .then(res=>{
// valid image
})
   .catch(error => {
// Image not found, Handle it here
}
```